# Transfer into dataframe after dir() or list.file()

Tags: r

I have 2 folders. They are supposed to have the same number of files with the same names but some are missing in one of the folder. Such as:

Folder A: "0001.pdf" "0002.pdf" "0003.pdf" "0004.pdf"

Folder B:
"0001.pdf", "0002.pdf", "0003.pdf"

So what I plan to do is to set data.frames with file names and then find out the `NA` in the list of Folder B.

```
setwd()
A = dir()
A = data.frame(A)
```

The structure did not show the correct levels, it just showed factors with 1 levels. Also after using `A = data.frame(A, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)`, I didn't work.

If the two lists are correct, the next step is supposed to be

```
A[-which(A$name%in%B$name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can browse to the directory where you folders are in. Lets call this directory `/Users/AbbyX/my_example_folder_with_two_folders`:

```
setwd("Users/AbbyX/my_example_folder_with_two_folders")
```

with the command `list.files()` you can list all the documents that are in that folder. You will see this:

```
list.files()
# [1] "Folder A"    "Folder B"
```

You can also see which files are inside `Folder A` and `Folder B`

```
list.files("Folder A")
# [1] "0001.pdf" "0002.pdf" "0003.pdf" "0004.pdf"
list.files("Folder B")
# [1] "0001.pdf" "0002.pdf" "0003.pdf"
```

You can then proceed to find the documents in `Folder A` that are not present in `Folder B` like:

```
A_files <- list.files("Folder A")
B_files <- list.files("Folder B")
A_files[!(A_files %in% B_Files)]
# [1] "0004.pdf"
```

Where the index `!(A_files %in% B_Files)` checks which elements of `A_files` are *not* in `B_files`.